# Lookup the data based on the Reporting date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I lookup the data from another sheet based on the Reporting date.

I want my lookup to be dynamic.
Every month the data change. For ex. I have data in January, In the month of Feb. data will change.

This is my Main Sheet.
[image: Main Sheet]

And this is my lookup sheet.
[image: Lookup Sheet]
Every month on this sheet it will change the data and reporting date.

So I have data in lookup sheet for the month of Feb. I want to dynamically lookup the data based on the month(Reporting Date) and column.
The output something like this,
[image: Output]

Sorry I'm quite new about the excel formula.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP?

Comment: Just a VLOOKUP, But I need to dynamic Vlookup, For ex. I have reporting date `2\29\2020` in Lookup Sheet, I need to get the data and post to Main Sheet in February Row, Same in March, etc.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? How is VLOOKUP not working?

Comment: I want something like `If Condition`, If the reporting date is equal to `2\29\2020` then lookup the data and post to Main File row of February. Something like that.